# What are the best practices when performing a Truncate in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, truncate, cassandra-3.0

I want to perform a `TRUNCATE` on multiple tables with around 25 million records, in clustered, multi-data-center environment. I would just like some advice on steps to take before/after the truncate to ensure that there aren't huge discrepancies between the nodes.

According to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html), a TRUNCATE deletes the SSTable holding the data. Does this mean that I'll need to set my consistency level to `ALL` before the truncate? Is a `nodetool repair` necessary after the operation?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4
```

Comment: if you have autosnapshot enabled in cassandra.yaml it will hardlink the data files so it is not immediately deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that all nodes are up before issuing this command.

Truncate will naturally propogate out over the cluster as long as all nodes remain up and available.

Truncate will automatically run as if CONSISTENCY is set to ALL which ensures that the command **only** returns after all nodes have deleted their data and fail if a node cannot be reached.

Repair is not necessary as there will not be any data to repair after the operation.

Comment: consistency level is ignored on truncate, theres a precondition that all nodes are up regardless (at least at current versions) https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/7082b64fc9a9a14c9f9cb9a492c0b25d109f4edc/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StorageProxy.java#L2527.

Comment: I was refereing to the scenario when a node goes down after truncate has already gone past this precondition. However, you are correct in that Truncate will act as if it has CONSISTENCY set to ALL no matter what CONSISTENCY level is set.

Comment: i am using DBeaver , able to delete from Dbeaver. But while am deleting from spring data program i am getting error " Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TruncateException: Error during truncate: Cannot achieve consistency level ALL
 at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:120) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar:na]
 What am I doing wrong here ??? please help me